# Boost regex does not match

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I made a python regular expression and now I'm supposed to code the program in C++.

I was told to use boost's regex by the respective person.

It is supposed to match a group of at least one to 80 lower alphanumeric characters including underscore followed by a backslash then another group of at least one to 80 lower alphanumeric characters again including an underscore and last but not least a question mark. The total string must be at least 1 character long and is not allowed to exceed 256.

Here is my python regex:

```
^((?P<grp1>[a-z0-9_]{1,80})/(?P<grp2>[a-z0-9_]{1,80})([?])){1,256}$
```

My current boost regex is:

```
^(([a-z0-9_]{1,80})\/([a-z0-9_]{1,80})([?])){1,256}$
```

Cut down basically my code would look like this:

```
boost::cmatch match;
bool isMatch;
boost::regex myRegex = "^(([a-z0-9_]{1,80})\/([a-z0-9_]{1,80})([?])){1,256}$";
isMatch = boost::regex_match(str.c_str(), match, myRegex);
```

Edit: whoops totally forgot the question xDD. My problem is quite simple: The regex doesn't match though it's supposed to.

Example matches would be:

- some/more?
- object/value?
- devel42/version_number?

Comment: Can you show an example that doesn't work. I just [tried a test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62da63bf5120eb97) and it printed true. Your example had a couple minor errors though.

Comment: @JesseGood This should be the answer, since you fixed the minor erros.

Comment: I've made an edit and posted some examples that are supposed to match. I've also tested online pages and it worked on them. @tgmath I've tried the regex without the slash before the backslash (supposed to escape the backslash sign from what I understood from a page about regular expressions) I've also tried [/] before it's not the problem I'm running into unfortunately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error was a `new line` sent to the server by the client on entering the respective string that would've been later compared.

Funny how the errors root is rarely where you expect it to be.

Anyways, thank you all for your answers. They gave me the ability to clean up my regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The last requirement

> The total string must be at least 1 character long and is not allowed to exceed 256.

is always true as your string is already limited from 3 to 162 characters. You have only to keep the first part of your regex:

```
^[a-z0-9_]{1,80}/[a-z0-9_]{1,80}\?$
```

Comment: Actually you're right. I'm gonna try that... Nope it's still not working :s I don't understand this. The other regex I've made as well works and it's the same thing except a different regex.

Comment: @PascalNeubert: What error did you get? I guess there is an error elsewhere because the regex is pretty simple and I'm sure it works well. Unfortunately, I don't know boost :-(

Comment: There's no error it just doesn't match. (returning false instead of true)

Answer (score 1):

My g++ gives me the warning "unknown escape sequence: '\/'"; that means you should use "\\/" instead of "\/". You need a backslash char stored in the string, and then let the regex parser eat it as a escaping trigger.

By the way, my boost also requires a constructor invocation, so

`boost::regex myRegex("^(([a-z0-9_]{1,80})\\/([a-z0-9_]{1,80})([?])){1,256}$");`

seems work.

You can also use C++11 raw string literal to avoid C++ escaping:

`boost::regex myRegex(R"(^(([a-z0-9_]{1,80})\/([a-z0-9_]{1,80})([?])){1,256}$)");`

By the way, testing `<regex>` in libstdc++ svn is welcome. It should come with GCC 4.9 ;)

Comment: Using the constructor invocation I get errors: ''' /home/pneubert/Projects/Gerrit/general/simplecomm/Parser.cpp:5: error: no match for call to '(boost::regex {aka boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char> >}) (const char [37])' ''' Okay I trued using "\\/" instead of "\/". Still doesn't match :/

Comment: @PascalNeubert My boost version is 1.55.0. By the way, I don't see any reason escaping '/'. You may try `"^(([a-z0-9_]{1,80})/([a-z0-9_]{1,80})([?])){1,256}$"`

Comment: Yeah, testing it without escaping and with escaping doesn't matter. The one that has been working still works and the other regex doesn't.